# Middleware for EMC Documentum and CMIS?

Tags: cms, ecm

I am developing a plan for a Documentum install and intend to access it via CMIS. I'm trying to determine if I need middleware to connect Documentum to CMIS client libraries?

I have a successful implementation with FileNet and CMIS and that requires the IBM CMIS Connector for FileNet. So a FileNet installation won't work OOTB with CMIS, you must have the connector.

Does the same apply to Documentum? Does EMC make a CMIS connector for Documentum? Or perhaps Documentum works OOTB with CMIS (doubtful but worth asking)?

Comment: Voting to close because I don't see this as a management issue/question, and I'm not sure it belongs on stackoverflow either

Comment: @JimB Please do some searching before closing out of ignorance. There are plenty of CMIS questions on this board. For better or worse, this is the board where it fits that best out of all the Stack Exchange run web sites.

Comment: In which case they should be closed as well.  Its a good topic for meta.

Comment: I searched - found 9, all ancient

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the Documentum CMIS application.  From the version 7.2 Deployment Guide:

> Documentum CMIS is a web application. To deploy Documentum CMIS, you deploy a Documentum CMIS web application archive file to an application server.